# Как переопределить метод наследованого класса в python оставив прошлый функционал?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ооп, django-admin

Столкнулся с такой задачей при работе с Django, что мне нужно добавить несколько строк кода в существующий метод, но при этом оставить весь оригинальный код. То есть не изменить полностью функцию, а только добавить в неё функционал. Как можно это сделать в python?

Пример:

```
@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if "stop-task" in request.POST:
        task.stop_calculation(obj.task_id, request.user.id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
```

Когда я добавляю действие для своей кнопки в админ панели Django, то все оригинальные кнопки ломаются, так как код, который отвечает за их работу больше нет. А копировать огромный участок кода из оригинального метода и вставлять себе мне кажется неправильно и неудобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ДО или ПОСЛЕ базового функционала, то через `super()`, в классе это будет работать так

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print('A')

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        super().test() # До
        print('B')
        # super().test() # После
```

Если надо вписаться в середину, то только копипаст или разделяйте метод на более мелкие методы

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае решение оказалось таким:

```
@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if "stop-task" in request.POST:
        task.stop_calculation(obj.task_id, request.user.id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
    return super(TaskAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

Не до конца понимаю как работает конструкция `return super(TaskAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)`, кто знает напишите, пожалуйста, в комментарии.